# Pivot with mixed data and added column

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2014

I have a TaskDetails table with fields like this:

```
JobNo (text)
TaskName (text name of task)
ACTUAL_DATE (A date)
FORECAST_DATE (F date)
TaskType (text code)
```

One record per job-task.

I am able to get it to pivot for the lists of tasknames as these columns

```
JobNo  Task1A  Task1F     Task2A    Task2F ....  
A123   1/1/20  5/12/19
```

One record per job, with each task's Forecast and Actual as columns

But I want to add a column for each task code's TaskType as:

```
JobNo  Task1A  Task1F   Task1T   Task2A    Task2F  Tast2T....  
A123   1/1/20  5/12/19  active   2/1/10    3/1/11  delayed
```

Same as above but adding a column that includes the TaskType alone with each pair of columns for the task's F and A dates.

This is existing code I'm using (and barely understand) for the jobname and the task date columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT JobNo 
    ,TaskName + 'F' AS TaskCode
    ,FORECAST_DATE AS TaskDate
    FROM Task_Details AS FcstDateQuery
WHERE FORECAST_DATE IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT JobNo
    ,TaskName + 'A' AS TaskCode
    ,ACTUAL_DATE AS TaskDate
    FROM Task_Details AS ActDateQuery
WHERE ACTUAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
) 
    AS TaskDateQuery
    PIVOT(MAX(TaskDate) FOR TaskCode IN (
         [Code1F]
        ,[Code1A]
        ,[Code2F]
        ,[Code2A]
        )
        )as Pivot1
```

Can't figure out how to add that column.

Sample data:

TaskDetails

```
JobNo, Taskname, Actual_Date,Forecast_Date,Tasktype
A111,  Name1,     1/1/20,     1/1/30,       delayed
A111,  Name2,     2/2/20,     3/3/20,       active
A222,  Name1,     3/3/20,     4/4/20,       cancel
A222,  Name2,     4/4/20,     5/5/20,       pending
```

Current output:

```
JobNo, Name1F, Name1A,  Name2F, Name2A
A111, 1/1/20,  1/1/30,  2/2/20, 3/3/20  
A222, 3/3/20,  4/4/20,  4/4//20, 5/5/20
```

Desired output

```
JobNo, Name1F, Name1A, Name1T,  Name2F, Name2A, Name2T
A111, 1/1/20,  1/1/30, delayed, 2/2/20, 3/3/20, active 
A222, 3/3/20,  4/4/20, cancel,  4/4//20, 5/5/20, pending
```

Each line in the task details table has one task, and it's 2 dates and status info.  I need the output to have one row per JobNo, and in each row, a column for each task date (working now) and another column for the task status (last part is what I need help with)

EDIT:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Per @ilyazakharov input, I noticed that answer cast the dates as strings.  That was the original problem I had really, I could not union the 2 datatypes.  If I cast the dates as stings, my original code works.  Pasted below.  But the output on all the date fields is varchar, I need dates where they are dates.  The sample code only has a few task names, the real data has hundreds.  Be great to get the output without having to do all that casting.  Or some more eloquent way.

I also got it to work by doing 2 pivots.  One for the tasks like I have now, and a different one for the char data field, then joining those 2 together.  Figured there would be a better way?

```
CREATE TABLE Task_Details
(
    JobNo             NVARCHAR(100),
    TaskName          NVARCHAR(100),
    ACTUAL_DATE       DATE,
    FORECAST_DATE     DATE,
    TaskType          NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Task_Details
  (
    JobNo,
    TaskName,
    ACTUAL_DATE,
    FORECAST_DATE,
    TaskType
  )
VALUES
('A111','Name1','2020-01-01','2030-01-01','delayed'),
('A111', 'Name2', '2020-02-02', '2020-03-03', 'ACTIVE'),
('A222', 'Name1', '2020-03-03', '2020-04-04', 'cancel'),
('A222', 'Name2', '2020-04-04', '2020-05-05', 'pending')

SELECT 
  JobNo
  ,cast(Name1F as smalldatetime) as Name1F
  ,cast(Name1A as smalldatetime) as Name1A
  ,Name1T
  ,cast(Name2F as smalldatetime) as Name2F
  ,cast(Name2A as smalldatetime) as Name2A
  ,Name2T

FROM (

SELECT JobNo 
    ,TaskName + 'T' AS TaskCode
    ,Tasktype AS TaskDate
    FROM deleteme_taskdet AS FcstDateQuery
WHERE FORECAST_DATE IS NOT NULL

union

SELECT JobNo 
    ,TaskName + 'F' AS TaskCode
    ,CAST(FORECAST_DATE AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS TaskDate

    FROM deleteme_taskdet AS FcstDateQuery
WHERE FORECAST_DATE IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT JobNo
    ,TaskName + 'A' AS TaskCode
    ,CAST(ACTUAL_DATE AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS TaskDate
    FROM deleteme_taskdet AS ActDateQuery
WHERE ACTUAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
) 
    AS TaskDateQuery
    PIVOT(MAX(TaskDate) FOR TaskCode IN (
     [Name1F]
    ,[Name1A]
    ,[Name1T]
,[Name2F]
    ,[Name2A]
    ,[Name2T]            )
        )as Pivot1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will greatly help us, help you.

Comment: Edited and added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should firstly unpivot table to create one column for both TaskType and TaskDate, and then pivot this new column.
Should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Task_Details
(
    JobNo             NVARCHAR(100),
    TaskName          NVARCHAR(100),
    ACTUAL_DATE       DATE,
    FORECAST_DATE     DATE,
    TaskType          NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Task_Details
  (
    JobNo,
    TaskName,
    ACTUAL_DATE,
    FORECAST_DATE,
    TaskType
  )
VALUES
('A111','Name1','2020-01-01','2030-01-01','delayed'),
('A111', 'Name2', '2020-02-02', '2020-03-03', 'ACTIVE'),
('A222', 'Name1', '2020-03-03', '2020-04-04', 'cancel'),
('A222', 'Name2', '2020-04-04', '2020-05-05', 'pending')

SELECT JobNo,
       cast([Name1A_TaskDate] as smalldatetime) AS Name1F,
       cast([Name1F_TaskDate] as smalldatetime) AS Name1A,
       [Name1F_TaskType]  AS Name1T,
       cast([Name2A_TaskDate] as smalldatetime) AS Name2F,
       cast([Name2F_TaskDate] as smalldatetime) AS Name2A,
       [Name2F_TaskType] AS Name2T
FROM   (
           SELECT JobNo,
                  task,
                  TaskCode + '_' + JOB  AS rr
           FROM   (
                      SELECT JobNo,
                             TaskName + 'F' AS TaskCode,
                             CAST(FORECAST_DATE AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS TaskDate,
                             TaskType
                      FROM   Task_Details AS FcstDateQuery
                      WHERE  FORECAST_DATE IS NOT NULL
                      UNION
                      SELECT JobNo,
                             TaskName + 'A' AS TaskCode,
                             CAST(ACTUAL_DATE AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS TaskDate,
                             TaskType
                      FROM   Task_Details AS ActDateQuery
                      WHERE  ACTUAL_DATE IS NOT NULL
                  )                     AS t
                  UNPIVOT(Task FOR JOB IN ([TaskDate], [TaskType])) AS h
       ) AS t 
       PIVOT(
           MAX(task) FOR rr IN ([Name1A_TaskDate], [Name1F_TaskDate], [Name1F_TaskType], [Name2A_TaskDate], 
                               [Name2F_TaskDate], [Name2F_TaskType])
       ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Close but there is only one task type per task name  So the output columns need to be:
`JobNo, Name1A, Name1F, Name1T,...`
not
`Jobno, Name1A, Name1AType, Name1F, Name1F_type...`

One set of F, A and type per taskname.

Comment: In FOR statement you can write ```MAX(task) FOR rr IN ([Name1A_TaskDate], [Name1A_TaskType], [Name2A_TaskDate], [Name1F_TaskDate], [Name2F_TaskDate], [Name2F_TaskType])```

Comment: Thank you.  I need the column names in the format "Name1A", "Name1F", and "Name1T", "Name2A"....  Can't get it to work

Comment: Could not get @ilyazakharov's suggestion to work quite right.  See edit above and comments in OP for what does work, albeit probably not the best way.

Comment: You can use aliases. I've edited the solution, check it out

Comment: Still need output as datetime, looks like I can do that at same place as alias

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you:

```
with cte1 as
( 
select jobno, taskname, forecast_date, actual_date, tasktype,
    row_number() over(partition by jobno order by jobno) as rownum
from job
)

select a.jobno,
    max(case when a.rownum = 1 then a.forecast_date else null end) as Name1F,
    max(case when a.rownum = 1 then a.actual_date else null end) as Name1A,
    max(case when a.rownum = 1 then a.tasktype else null end) as Name1T,
    max(case when b.rownum = 2 then b.forecast_date else null end) as Name2F,
    max(case when b.rownum = 2 then b.actual_date else null end) as Name2A,
    max(case when b.rownum = 2 then b.tasktype else null end) as Name2T
from cte1 a
inner join cte1 b on a.jobno = b.jobno
where a.rownum = 1 and b.rownum = 2
group by a.jobno
```